# parsing logfile, but cant strip brackets

Tags: python

So im trying to parse a logfile, and ive only found one way to split the string into three parts, date, error and message. I can easily do this with regex, but in order to learn im trying to find other ways. The end game is to parse logfiles, split the data into three parts and then depending on the flags you choose, print statistics. The log is formatted like this:

```
[Tue Nov 06 09:41:10 2020] [type] message
```

```py
for line in f.readlines():
    details = line.split(']')[0], line.split(']')[1], line.split(']')[2]
    details = [x.strip() for x in details]
    structure = {key:value for key, value in zip(order, details)}
    data.append(structure)
```

This of course gives me output:

```
"date": "[date",
"type": "[log",
```

I have several other examples of other ways ive tried to split and then strip these characters, one way would be:

```
details = line.strip('[').split(']')[0], line.split(']')[1], line.split(']')[2]
```

and this would strip the [ bracket from the date string. That leaves the type, and if i do the same strip again but on the first position above, it doesnt strip. If i strip before the split in the same forloop, it doesnt strip anything at all. Like i said, ive tried to manipulate this in a hundred different ways and i think i need some input on the correct way to do this as im stuck.

Comment: Why not using regex ? your approach is not understandable

Comment: Ive heard several times that regex is slow and there are other faster and better ways to go about it in python. And i think for this particular example, i just wanted to challenge myself and try to get it done without regex.

and one my question is two parts, why would it strip the date bracket but not the type bracket? It works for the first one, whats the difference in the second strip?

and the other question is, without regex, how would i split and strip a string like this? Is it even possible?

Comment: @scarlek this is the tipical use case for regex. I'd be interested if you heard about "faster and better" ways to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split by one (e.g, closing) bracket, then strip another (opening) one

```py
details = line.split(']')
details = [x.strip('[ ') for x in details]
structure = dict(zip(order, details))
```

---

But guys from the comments are very much right: regex solution will be much simpler and more maintainable.  Something along the lines of:

```
\[(?P<date>.+?)\] \[(?P<type>[a-z]+?)\] (?P<message>.+)
```

[See it in action at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zXrkGb/1)